# Easiest way to store a "table" of data in Objective-C for sorting?

Tags: objective-c

Say I have a data table with 3 fields:

```
uid {1,2,3}
username {john,bob,martha}
address {"1234 asdf way","5432 12th st", "9875 asdf drvie" }
```

If I wanted the ability to sort on any of these fields, what would be a suggested method of storing this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it in an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`, then use the method `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` to sort on any attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Jus create a class

```
    @interface Bio:nsobject
     {
     NSString * UID;
     NSString * Username;
     NSString * Address;
     }
   @end

  -(NSMutableArray *) GetALLBio()
   {
  //object for array
    NSmutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  //
  //sqlite record iteration starts
  Bio *obj=[[Bio alloc]init];//create instance of bio class
  obj.uid=get the record from sqlite current row iteration
  obj.username.....
  obj.address...

 [arr addobject:obj];
//sqlite record iteration ends
 return  arr;
 }
```

ViewCOntroller

```
DAL *dobj=[[DAL alloc]init];
 NSMutableArray* arobj=[[NSmutableArray alloc]init]; 
 arobj=[dobj GetALLBio];
 for(id in arobj)
 {
 id.UID
 id.UserName
 id.Address
 }
```

i hope it helps likwise u could create a separate DAL.....